# Keyboard Not Working in Ubuntu 18.04, Work in Windows Dual Boot

Tags: boot, 18.04, keyboard, login, mouse

So everything works fine for my windows boot. I upgraded my ubuntu from 16 to 18 and everything went bad on the ubuntu side. On the login screen neither my laptop mouse nor keyboard work, I had to plug in external via usb for them to get it to work. After login, the mouse works, but the keyboard does not work.

I tried all solutions I could find on here, like xserver xorg keyboard thing, bouncy keys, slow keys etc. I really cannot figure this out and its a big pain to deal with as I only have limited number of usb ports. This is such a pain, it will be very helpful if someone can find me a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by upgrading to ubuntu 19.10

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the board and then re-attach it.

Depending on laptop.

Or

Plug in a USB keyboard and see if the problem persists.

Normally, every keyboard should have a generic driver already for Ubuntu.

Something is not connected right.

Or

you messed up on install and chose another keyboard.

Comment: I am currently using a USB keyboard for ubuntu, but its a big pain, I want to use the usb ports for other things like connecting to android phone etc.

They laptop keyboard works fine on windows... I don't think its a hardware issue..