# laptop keyboard is not working on ubuntu

Tags: boot

well , I firstly installed ubuntu 20.0 and my keyboard as well as cursor didn't work, as my laptop has 4gb RAM so I thought downgrading it to 18.0 might work but it still doesn't.. Is there any idea what I could do ? i had dual booted my laptop and things are properly working in windows 10 .

Comment: This question looks very similar to yours. https://askubuntu.com/q/1203357/1110324

Comment: Ubuntu's main releases are *year.month* in format, and since there is no month 0 thus no release in that 0 month, I can only assume you're not using Ubuntu at all.  Ubuntu also has a different product that uses the *yy* format, but they are incompatible (a different product) so your question is unclear as written (there are no such releases as you mention).  Were you actually using Ubuntu? or did you try & use fakes?